# Javascript event handler with parameter

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to set the onmousemove event for an svg element.  The code below works in chrome, but in firefox it is not setting the onmousemove property correctly every time.  After the 2nd change it gets messed up.

```
mysvg.setAttribute('onmousemove','window.updateXY(evt,' + that.chartNumber + ')');
```

mysvg is still the correct svg element according to firebug:  svg#chart0

the svg property onmousemove says function(e) instead of onmousemove(evt) when it gets messed up, but no error is reported in firebug

Edited to show more code:

```
var YAxis = function(mysvg,chartNumber){
            this.chartNumber = chartNumber;
            var that = this;
            var g = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "g");
            this.id = 'YAxis' + chartNumber;
            g.id = this.id;
            mysvg.appendChild(g);
            var shift = false;
            this.selected = false;


            this.yScale = function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
                that.origY = e.pageY;
                that.shift = e.ctrlKey;
                mysvg.onmousemove = that.dragY;
                mysvg.onmouseup = that.dropY;
            }

            this.dragY = function(e) {
                var chart = charts[that.chartNumber];
                if(chart.log)
                    displayXYText.innerHTML = 'range: ' + Math.round(Math.pow(10,chart.max*(1 + (e.pageY - that.origY)/(chart.height)))*100)/100  + '-' + Math.round(Math.pow(10,chart.min*(1 - (e.pageY - that.origY)/(chart.height)))*100)/100;
                else
                    displayXYText.innerHTML = 'range: ' + Math.round(chart.max*(1 + (e.pageY - that.origY)/(chart.height))*100)/100  + '-' + Math.round(chart.min*(1 - (e.pageY - that.origY)/(chart.height))*100)/100;
            }
            this.dropY = function(e) {
                var chart = charts[that.chartNumber];
                if(that.shift){
                    var range = (chart.max - chart.min)*Math.round((e.pageY - that.origY)/(chart.height)*1000)/1000;
                    chart.max += range;
                    chart.min += range;
                }else{
                    var range = chart.max - chart.min;
                    chart.max *= 1 + Math.round((e.pageY - that.origY)/(chart.height)*1000)/1000;
                    chart.min *= 1 - Math.round((e.pageY - that.origY)/(chart.height)*1000)/1000;
                    if(chart.max <= chart.min){
                        chart.max = chart.min + range;
                    }
                }


                mysvg.setAttribute('onmousemove','window.updateXY(event,' + that.chartNumber + ')');
                //mysvg.onmousemove = updateXY(e,that.chartNumber);//function() { updateXY(e,that.chartNumber)}; //set back to orig function
                //mysvg.setAttribute('onmousemove','updateXY(evt,' + that.chartNumber + ')');
                //console.debug(mysvg.onmousemove.textContent);

                mysvg.setAttribute('onmouseup','window.mouseUp(event)');
                //console.debug("got here onmousemove");
                chart.redraw();
            }
```

}

Comment: What are `window.updateXY`, `evt` and `that.chartNumber`? If `evt` is supposed to be the event object, you should use `event` instead.

Comment: Use `addEventListener()` for the callback and `data-X` attributes to store the chartNumber.

Comment: I think he needs to show a little more code.

Comment: It shows `function(e)` and not `function(event)`?

Comment: changing `evt` to `event` doesn''t make a difference.   Still works in chrome not in firefox.  I have a separate function to call the `updateXY` code, so I'm not sure how to use the `data-X` attributes to pass that parameter

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the methods above but none worked properly in firefox.  The solution was to not pass any parameters other than `event` to the updateXY function.  When the other parameters were undefined, run separate logic to determine what the parameters should be in that case. Once the code is in the `window` frame, you can use `setAttribute` like you normally do.  #FirefoxOOPfail